# Failing to scale an ACS cluster due to missing ServicePrincipalProfile

Tags: azure-container-service

I'm trying to scale an ACS cluster that is running k8s. From the Azure CLI I get the error below, and the Azure Portal results in a similar error message. It seems somehow my k8s cluster isn't setup with a Service Principal correctly?

> "ServicePrincipalProfile must be specified with Orchestrator
> Kubernetes"

I find this odd because I did use the az ad sp create-for-rbac command to create service principal for the subscription. I then used the resulting appId and password with the az acs create command (in the --service-principal and --client-secret options).

Example:

> az ad sp create-for-rbac --role="Contributor" --scopes="/subscriptions/my-subscription-guid"
>
> az acs create -n=myk8skube -g=myresgrp --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --agent-count=2 --generate-ssh-keys --windows --admin-username=myuser --admin-password=mypassword --service-principal=appId --client-secret=password

The cluster is running fine, I can scale pods, but I can't scale nodes. How did I get in this state and more importantly how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue for scale of ACS cluster in preview regions. The fix rolled out across the world by 8/31/2017.

Comment: Jingtao, I'm still seeing the same problem as of now. Is there anything I need to do to address this on my end? I assume I don't need to deploy a new cluster to fix it, correct?

Comment: Please report back if you are still seeing it. Existing cluster is OK.

Comment: The problem was solved by deploying a new cluster. my existing cluster continues to fail.